# license enforcement system has been tampered with on calling to wkhtmltopdf.exe - win server 2008

Tags: c#

On our production server, win 2008 64 bit, running a .NET 3.5 site under NETWORK SERVICE account, I suddenly get this message in the error log "server cannot open this program because the license enforcement system has been tampered with or become corrupted"
Launching wkhtmltopdf.exe under my account (or under SYSTEM account, usign technique described here - http://geek.hubkey.com/2008/02/impersonating-built-in-service-account.html) - works succesfully.
All software is licensed and we havent installed anything new on the server for some time (weeks).

The exception is thrown when calling a wkhtmltopdf.exe to generate PDF from pages.

Does anyone have an idea of how to find out what's wrong here?

Here is stacktrace:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): Windows cannot open this program because the license enforcement system has been tampered with or become corrupted]
System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) +614
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() +56
KPI.DownloadWoordenschatTest() in ..\KPI.aspx.cs:1579
KPI.btnLogin5_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ..\KPI.aspx.cs:1451
KPI.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in ..\KPI.aspx.cs:109
System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

And here is code snippet, where problem is reported:

```
Process pdfConverterProcess = new Process();
            pdfConverterProcess.StartInfo.FileName = Server.MapPath("~/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe");
            pdfConverterProcess.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            pdfConverterProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@" ""{0}"" ""{1}"" --header-html ""{2}&np=1"" --footer-html ""{3}&np=1""  --margin-top 2.5cm --header-spacing 7", requestUrl, filePath, pdfHeaderURL, pdfFooterURL);
            pdfConverterProcess.Start(); (this is line 1579)
            pdfConverterProcess.WaitForExit();
            pdfConverterProcess.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this, but when I faced this, I noticed that the error went away after I installed [Windows Management Framework 3.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595)

You can check if this is the case with your setup.

Comment: Actually, error was gone in 3-5 minutes and was not reproduced anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

I recently had an event where I got this error on every call to Rotativa WkhtmltopdfDriver ConvertHtml.

I then tested that wkhtmltopdf was working with

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\SomeApplication\Rotativa>wkhtmltopdf.exe c:\pdf\test.txt c:\pdf\test.pdf
```

This left me with few options, as my search results were not great.

**Thankfully, upon restarting the server my problem was resolved without requiring any additional steps.**

In my case we had made no recent changes to the application when this started happening, and Rotativa had been working for well over a year with no prior problems once we got it up and running.

I would recommend that anyone having such issues similarly attempt to prove that wkhtmltopdf is working fine on its own, or not, as that should help further troubleshooting.  And attempt a restart before you go and start changing anything.

In my case I presume that either a windows service wasn't running, or similarly that some other required piece had found it's way into an error state.